# Check if image is cached via PHP

Tags: php, image, caching

I wrote a blog CMS and whenever I upload an image, I upload it with several scaled versions to save page size.

This is what I'm trying to approach:

```
function getThumbnail($postID) {
    $url = "cdn.url.com/img/thumb/$postID";

    if(cached("$url.png")) {
        return "$url.png";
    } else {
        return "$url-125x125.png";
    }
}
```

Basically, if the user already cached the unscaled, big image on somewhere like homepage, I don't want to give the user a new scaled one to waste data. And if the user didn't cache the unscaled image, I want to give the user a scaled, appropriate one.

Note: I am not a PHP developer and I wrote the example above here without testing. If there are some errors, don't hesitate to fix them.

Comment: I think you can not check if image cached in browser via php.

Comment: That is not possible. You would need to save that information in a Session or a Cookie. But on the next visit that will be lost. On the other hand, you could add cache headers and let the browser do the magic.